# Openpyxl is working with 2 commands but crashed when I input a 3rd

Tags: python, openpyxl

This code works

```
# Create a new Excel workbook and add a sheet
workbook = Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active

# Resize the first column and first row
sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width=2
sheet.row_dimensions['1'].height=10

# Save the workbook to a file
workbook.save('Documentation.xlsx')

print("Excel document created successfully.")
```

This code doesn't work

```
# Create a new Excel workbook and add a sheet
workbook = Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active

# Resize the first column and first row
sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width=2
sheet.row_dimensions['1'].height=10
sheet['A1'] = 'Hello'

# Save the workbook to a file
workbook.save('Documentation.xlsx')

print("Excel document created successfully.")
```

and here is the Terminal Output for the failed run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pcristea\Documents\Learning.py", line 59, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\pcristea\Documents\Learning.py", line 54, in main
    workbook.save('Documentation.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\pcristea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 386, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\pcristea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 294, in save_workbook
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Users\pcristea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 275, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Users\pcristea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 77, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\pcristea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 215, in _write_worksheets
    self.write_worksheet(ws)
  File "C:\Users\pcristea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 200, in write_worksheet
    writer.write()
  File "C:\Users\pcristea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 359, in write
    self.write_rows()
  File "C:\Users\pcristea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 124, in write_rows
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pcristea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 117, in rows
    return sorted(rows.items())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
Exception ignored in atexit callback: <function _openpyxl_shutdown at 0x0000026428AECA40>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pcristea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 32, in _openpyxl_shutdown
    os.remove(path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird: 'C:\\Users\\pcristea\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\openpyxl.tky3u7x7'
```

The entire code is execute but saving the workbook doesn't work if 3 or more commands are executed.

I am trying to create an Excel document with specific formating and data.

Comment: Why is the row number, 1, in quotes in this line  `sheet.row_dimensions['1'].height=10`. Remove the quotes on both the code that works and the code that doesn't.

Comment: Basically the reason the difference is the fact that the first code sample does not write any data to any cell so the sheet is empty and openpyxl code doesn't check rows on save. On the second code sample where cell A1 is written to, the openpyxl code performs certain tasks which includes checking rows with populated cells. Part of this check dumps an error because the row dimension key is `'1'` rather than `1`